# vagrant ssh worker1 doesn't work without much feedback

Tags: vagrant

I'm using [this repo](https://github.com/tdi/vagrant-docker-swarm) to create a docker swarm cluster with vagrant and virtualbox.

When I do `vagrant up`, all 3 VM create and provision with no issue.

But at the time I want to connect via `vagrant ssh worker1` I get this issue:

```
... // Log is too long, had too cut it
SharedFolderNameMachineMapping1="vagrant"
SharedFolderPathMachineMapping1="\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\info\\code\\vagrant-docker-swarm"
VRDEActiveConnection="off"
VRDEClients==0
videocap="off"
videocapaudio="off"
capturescreens="0"
capturefilename="C:\\Users\\info\\VirtualBox VMs\\ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1547555682734_91505\\ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1547555682734_91505.webm"
captureres="1024x768"
capturevideorate=512
capturevideofps=25
captureopts=""
GuestMemoryBalloon=0
GuestOSType="Linux26_64"
GuestAdditionsRunLevel=2
GuestAdditionsVersion="4.3.36_Ubuntu r105129"
GuestAdditionsFacility_VirtualBox Base Driver=50,1547555723996
GuestAdditionsFacility_VirtualBox System Service=50,1547555740594
GuestAdditionsFacility_Seamless Mode=0,1547555723996
GuestAdditionsFacility_Graphics Mode=0,1547555723996
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::SSHExec:0x0000000004c815c8>
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "58ad4284-22f4-43a3-9b9b-132e30589f84", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stdout: name="vagrant-docker-swarm_worker1_1547555699806_19311"
groups="/"
ostype="Ubuntu (64-bit)"
UUID="58ad4284-22f4-43a3-9b9b-132e30589f84"
CfgFile="C:\\Users\\info\\VirtualBox VMs\\vagrant-docker-swarm_worker1_1547555699806_19311\\vagrant-docker-swarm_worker1_1547555699806_19311.vbox"
SnapFldr="C:\\Users\\info\\VirtualBox VMs\\vagrant-docker-swarm_worker1_1547555699806_19311\\Snapshots"
LogFldr="C:\\Users\\info\\VirtualBox VMs\\vagrant-docker-swarm_worker1_1547555699806_19311\\Logs"
hardwareuuid="58ad4284-22f4-43a3-9b9b-132e30589f84"
memory=512
pagefusion="off"
vram=12
cpuexecutioncap=100
hpet="off"
cpu-profile="host"
chipset="piix3"
firmware="BIOS"
cpus=1
pae="off"
longmode="on"
triplefaultreset="off"
apic="on"
x2apic="off"
nested-hw-virt="off"
cpuid-portability-level=0
bootmenu="messageandmenu"
boot1="disk"
boot2="none"
boot3="none"
boot4="none"
acpi="on"
ioapic="on"
biosapic="apic"
biossystemtimeoffset=0
rtcuseutc="on"
hwvirtex="on"
nestedpaging="on"
largepages="off"
vtxvpid="on"
vtxux="on"
paravirtprovider="legacy"
effparavirtprovider="none"
VMState="running"
VMStateChangeTime="2019-01-15T13:40:43.369000000"
monitorcount=1
accelerate3d="off"
accelerate2dvideo="off"
teleporterenabled="off"
teleporterport=0
teleporteraddress=""
teleporterpassword=""
tracing-enabled="off"
tracing-allow-vm-access="off"
tracing-config=""
autostart-enabled="off"
autostart-delay=0
defaultfrontend=""
storagecontrollername0="SATAController"
storagecontrollertype0="IntelAhci"
storagecontrollerinstance0="0"
storagecontrollermaxportcount0="30"
storagecontrollerportcount0="1"
storagecontrollerbootable0="on"
"SATAController-0-0"="C:\Users\info\VirtualBox VMs\ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64\box-disk1_1.vmdk"
"SATAController-ImageUUID-0-0"="c6f0991b-044d-47b7-891c-325ea7cb7cf4"
natnet1="nat"
macaddress1="08002729A82F"
cableconnected1="on"
nic1="nat"
nictype1="82540EM"
nicspeed1="0"
mtu="0"
sockSnd="64"
sockRcv="64"
tcpWndSnd="64"
tcpWndRcv="64"
Forwarding(0)="ssh,tcp,127.0.0.1,2200,,22"
hostonlyadapter2="VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2"
macaddress2="080027BDAFB5"
cableconnected2="on"
nic2="hostonly"
nictype2="82540EM"
nicspeed2="0"
nic3="none"
nic4="none"
nic5="none"
nic6="none"
nic7="none"
nic8="none"
hidpointing="ps2mouse"
hidkeyboard="ps2kbd"
uart1="off"
uart2="off"
uart3="off"
uart4="off"
lpt1="off"
lpt2="off"
audio="none"
audio_in="on"
audio_out="on"
clipboard="disabled"
draganddrop="disabled"
SessionName="headless"
VideoMode="720,400,0"@0,0 1
vrde="off"
usb="off"
ehci="off"
xhci="off"
SharedFolderNameMachineMapping1="vagrant"
SharedFolderPathMachineMapping1="\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\info\\code\\vagrant-docker-swarm"
VRDEActiveConnection="off"
VRDEClients==0
videocap="off"
videocapaudio="off"
capturescreens="0"
capturefilename="C:\\Users\\info\\VirtualBox VMs\\ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1547555682734_91505\\ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1547555682734_91505.webm"
captureres="1024x768"
capturevideorate=512
capturevideofps=25
captureopts=""
GuestMemoryBalloon=0
GuestOSType="Linux26_64"
GuestAdditionsRunLevel=2
GuestAdditionsVersion="4.3.36_Ubuntu r105129"
GuestAdditionsFacility_VirtualBox Base Driver=50,1547555723996
GuestAdditionsFacility_VirtualBox System Service=50,1547555740594
GuestAdditionsFacility_Seamless Mode=0,1547555723996
GuestAdditionsFacility_Graphics Mode=0,1547555723996
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
DEBUG virtualbox_6_0: Searching for SSH port: 22
DEBUG virtualbox_6_0: read_forward_ports: uuid=58ad4284-22f4-43a3-9b9b-132e30589f84 active_only=false
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "58ad4284-22f4-43a3-9b9b-132e30589f84", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stdout: name="vagrant-docker-swarm_worker1_1547555699806_19311"
groups="/"
ostype="Ubuntu (64-bit)"
UUID="58ad4284-22f4-43a3-9b9b-132e30589f84"
CfgFile="C:\\Users\\info\\VirtualBox VMs\\vagrant-docker-swarm_worker1_1547555699806_19311\\vagrant-docker-swarm_worker1_1547555699806_19311.vbox"
SnapFldr="C:\\Users\\info\\VirtualBox VMs\\vagrant-docker-swarm_worker1_1547555699806_19311\\Snapshots"
LogFldr="C:\\Users\\info\\VirtualBox VMs\\vagrant-docker-swarm_worker1_1547555699806_19311\\Logs"
hardwareuuid="58ad4284-22f4-43a3-9b9b-132e30589f84"
memory=512
pagefusion="off"
vram=12
cpuexecutioncap=100
hpet="off"
cpu-profile="host"
chipset="piix3"
firmware="BIOS"
cpus=1
pae="off"
longmode="on"
triplefaultreset="off"
apic="on"
x2apic="off"
nested-hw-virt="off"
cpuid-portability-level=0
bootmenu="messageandmenu"
boot1="disk"
boot2="none"
boot3="none"
boot4="none"
acpi="on"
ioapic="on"
biosapic="apic"
biossystemtimeoffset=0
rtcuseutc="on"
hwvirtex="on"
nestedpaging="on"
largepages="off"
vtxvpid="on"
vtxux="on"
paravirtprovider="legacy"
effparavirtprovider="none"
VMState="running"
VMStateChangeTime="2019-01-15T13:40:43.369000000"
monitorcount=1
accelerate3d="off"
accelerate2dvideo="off"
teleporterenabled="off"
teleporterport=0
teleporteraddress=""
teleporterpassword=""
tracing-enabled="off"
tracing-allow-vm-access="off"
tracing-config=""
autostart-enabled="off"
autostart-delay=0
defaultfrontend=""
storagecontrollername0="SATAController"
storagecontrollertype0="IntelAhci"
storagecontrollerinstance0="0"
storagecontrollermaxportcount0="30"
storagecontrollerportcount0="1"
storagecontrollerbootable0="on"
"SATAController-0-0"="C:\Users\info\VirtualBox VMs\ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64\box-disk1_1.vmdk"
"SATAController-ImageUUID-0-0"="c6f0991b-044d-47b7-891c-325ea7cb7cf4"
natnet1="nat"
macaddress1="08002729A82F"
cableconnected1="on"
nic1="nat"
nictype1="82540EM"
nicspeed1="0"
mtu="0"
sockSnd="64"
sockRcv="64"
tcpWndSnd="64"
tcpWndRcv="64"
Forwarding(0)="ssh,tcp,127.0.0.1,2200,,22"
hostonlyadapter2="VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2"
macaddress2="080027BDAFB5"
cableconnected2="on"
nic2="hostonly"
nictype2="82540EM"
nicspeed2="0"
nic3="none"
nic4="none"
nic5="none"
nic6="none"
nic7="none"
nic8="none"
hidpointing="ps2mouse"
hidkeyboard="ps2kbd"
uart1="off"
uart2="off"
uart3="off"
uart4="off"
lpt1="off"
lpt2="off"
audio="none"
audio_in="on"
audio_out="on"
clipboard="disabled"
draganddrop="disabled"
SessionName="headless"
VideoMode="720,400,0"@0,0 1
vrde="off"
usb="off"
ehci="off"
xhci="off"
SharedFolderNameMachineMapping1="vagrant"
SharedFolderPathMachineMapping1="\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\info\\code\\vagrant-docker-swarm"
VRDEActiveConnection="off"
VRDEClients==0
videocap="off"
videocapaudio="off"
capturescreens="0"
capturefilename="C:\\Users\\info\\VirtualBox VMs\\ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1547555682734_91505\\ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1547555682734_91505.webm"
captureres="1024x768"
capturevideorate=512
capturevideofps=25
captureopts=""
GuestMemoryBalloon=0
GuestOSType="Linux26_64"
GuestAdditionsRunLevel=2
GuestAdditionsVersion="4.3.36_Ubuntu r105129"
GuestAdditionsFacility_VirtualBox Base Driver=50,1547555723996
GuestAdditionsFacility_VirtualBox System Service=50,1547555740594
GuestAdditionsFacility_Seamless Mode=0,1547555723996
GuestAdditionsFacility_Graphics Mode=0,1547555723996
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
DEBUG virtualbox_6_0:   - [1, "ssh", 2200, 22, "127.0.0.1"]
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Users\\info\\DOCUME~1\\MOBAXT~1\\slash\\bin/ssh.EXE"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
ERROR warden: Error occurred:  (216)
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
 INFO environment: Running hook: environment_unload
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 1 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: environment_unload #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x00000000045fe610>
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:158:in `rescue in execute':  (216) (Vagrant::Util::Subprocess::LaunchError)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:151:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:22:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/util/ssh.rb:99:in `exec'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/ssh_exec.rb:39:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_running.rb:16:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_created.rb:16:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:26:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:239:in `action_raw'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:208:in `block in action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:190:in `block in action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:194:in `action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/plugins/commands/ssh/command.rb:66:in `block in execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:238:in `block in with_target_vms'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:232:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:232:in `with_target_vms'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/plugins/commands/ssh/command.rb:46:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:58:in `execute'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:291:in `cli'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.3/gems/vagrant-2.2.3/bin/vagrant:182:in `<main>'
```

I don't really know how to debug it... Any idea ?

I use virtualbox 6.0 and vagrant 2.2.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thats an issue with mobaxterm, its been reported by others (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/lELRBz5npUc)

you could use Cygwin or git bash  on windows, it should clear the error and allow ssh to work.

Comment: You are quite right ! with git bash, I have actually no problems! If you still want to use mobaXterm, you can do: vagrant ssh-config > vagrant-ssh and then connect via:  ssh -F vagrant-ssh you-machine

Comment: Its true for me also! When I used cygwin or windows cmd. its working fine!

Comment: as suggested in the google groups thread, first ran "cmd.exe" and then "vagrant ssh node". works like charm! thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the answer, mobaxterm provides option to run cmd.exe as preferred shell for the session. Add the vagrant directory as start up directory and the vagrant command as in this screenshot.

[image]